# ffmpeg Filter atrim has an unconnected output

Tags: ffmpeg

My `ffmpeg` command :

```
"ffmpeg -y -i cleanBgMusic.mp3 -filter_complex 
[0]atrim=start=0.0:duration=11.20833333333[a11];
[a11]concat=n=1:v=0:a=1 
-b:a 96k
-c:a libmp3lame 
/Users/hanli/Documents/animSource/output/__pik_bgmusic_tmp.mp3"
```

Then i received error：

> Filter atrim has an unconnected output.

The output [a11] is used for concat, so why occur the error.

Comment: Run the command with `-report` and share it.

Comment: @Mulvya , Thanks for your help ,but i has solved the problem ，just wrapped the filter's parameters in quotation marks. like this :

   ' "ffmpeg -y -i cleanBgMusic.mp3 -filter_complex 
    [0]atrim=start=0.0:duration=11.20833333333[a11];
    [a11]concat=n=1:v=0:a=1 
    -b:a 96k
    -c:a libmp3lame 
    /Users/hanli/Documents/animSource/output/__pik_bgmusic_tmp.mp3"'